# I can't add images with pygame

Tags: python, pygame

So this is the code that defines the images:

```
sun_img = pygame.image.load('assets/images/sun.png')
bg_img = pygame.image.load('assets/images/sky.png')
```

And this is my main game loop:

```
run = True
while run:

    WIN.blit(bg_img, (0, 0))
    WIN.blit(sun_img(100, 100))
    pygame.display.update()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
pygame.quit()
```

But when I run my code, this happens:
line 16, in  WIN.blit(sun_img(100, 100)) TypeError: 'pygame.Surface' object is not callable

Please help me {{{(>_<)}}}

Comment: You're missing a comma after "sun_img" in your call to blit: `WIN.blit(sun_img, (100, 100))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WIN.blit(sun_image, (0, 0))` you forgot to put a comma after sun_image

Comment: There is a recommendation not to answer typo-question. Questions like these are off-topic and should not be answered but closed as they are not helpful to other contributors. The questions will be closed and finally deleted. If the question is deleted, your gained reputation points will be lost.